# control windows 7 taskbar grouping for my application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, taskbar

My program needs to open a series of information windows when requested by a user, and would like to implement some kind of custom grouping on the windows 7 taskbar.

Desired functionality: All of my information windows should be grouped together (if grouping is enabled on the users system, that is) but my main window should NOT be grouped with the information windows.

I can not spawn a new process for my information windows.

My thought process is that there could be a way to modify the window handle of the information window somehow to get the taskbar to group it separately but I honestly don't even know where to start with this.

**EDIT**

Ive found some new information. I may be able to do something with `SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow` as stated here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378459(v=vs.85).aspx#where

> ...As a property of any of the application's running windows. This can be set in one of two ways:
>   If different windows owned by one process require different AppUserModelIDs to control taskbar grouping, use SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow to retrieve the window's property store and set the AppUserModelID as a window property.

Comment: Assign your windows the same appID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the [Windows API Code Pack for .NET](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) and the following code:

```
TaskbarManager.Instance.SetApplicationIdForSpecificWindow(window, guid);
```

Window assigned with the same id will be grouped together - windows with a unique id will have a separate taskbar icon.

Comment: How to get window handle and what (gu)id is this?

Comment: @Brackets : you can use any guid. Windows with the same guid will be grouped together - windows with a unique id will have a separate taskbar icon.

Answer (score 2):

[Application User Model IDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378459%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

"If different windows owned by one process require different AppUserModelIDs to control taskbar grouping, use [SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378430%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the window's property store and set the AppUserModelID as a window property."

Comment: This worked for me. I couldn't use the Windows API Code Pack as we're a .NET 2.0 app.

Comment: My problem was that our app can also be launched via COM, and when it was it would always combine in the taskbar grouping and use the same icon and taskbar button as the parent app that was calling the child app via COM.

This is the VB.NET code that did the trick:

`Public Declare Function SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID Lib "Shell32.dll" Alias "SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID" ( ByVal AppID As String) As Integer)`
`SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID("CompanyName.ProductName.SubProduct.1.0.0.0")`